Rotating Projectile Godot
I have this projectile code in godot:
the projectiled object is an 2d missile.
extends RigidBody2D


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    var angle = 60
    var power = 1500000
    
    var force = Vector2(-sin(angle) * power , cos(angle) * power)  # Push to the right

    apply_central_force(force)

    

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass


but a projectile in real life rotates in mid air, i want this to happen also in godot and the projectile be more realistic

It looks like you want your RigidBody2D scene (projectile object) to rotate after it has been spawned. Luckily, RigidBody2D has a built-in function, set_angular_velocity() to change a scene's angular velocity. Setting this value will cause the scene to forever rotate with the given speed, until it is set again or acted upon by friction or damping of some sort.
In this example, the function is used in _ready(), but it would also work elsewhere, even in _process() if you wanted to make sure the angular velocity was never-changing.
# Set a rotation speed for the RigidBody2D
export var myAngularVelocity = 1.0
func _ready():
    var angle = 60
    var power = 1500000
    var force = Vector2(-sin(angle) * power , cos(angle) * power)  # Push to the right
    apply_central_force(force)
    set_angular_velocity(myAngularVelocity ) # Set angular velocity!


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass


What behavior is not occurring which you expected? In the above code, the ball (RigidBody2D) would rotate in the air when spawned. To modify the physics, the scene's gravity and friction can be directly adjusted. Hope this helps.

Replace your _process function with the following code:
func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    if linear_velocity.length() > 10.0:
        rotation = atan2(linear_velocity.y, linear_velocity.x)

As long as the rocket is moving at least 10 pixels per second, it will be rotated to face in the direction it's currently travelling at. This code assumes the front of the rocket to face the positive X axis by default.
Depending on your needs, you may not need the condition at all (example: rocket is destroyed when it hits something), or need a completely different one (example: rocket is able to fall and freely tumble). You could also experiment with changing the rotation gradually using rotation = lerp(rotation, atan2(linear_velocity.y, linear_velocity.x), 20 * delta).

I can't write comments yet, so I will have to say this here: Jonathan F.'s answer is not satisfactory because an object flying on a non-circular path (such as a parabola) does not rotate at a constant speed. The angular velocity would need to be recomputed every frame, but what is the correct formula to make sure that the rocket is always facing the direction of motion? In the end, perhaps a mix of both is needed: Setting the rotation to make sure it doesn't drift off, and setting the angular velocity so that the rocket behaves nicely in physics interactions.
